# Two GitLab installations - one accepts ssh key auth, the other doesn't

Tags: authentication, ssh, key, gitlab

I've got the same public key distributed to 2 GitLab installations.

One (host: gitrepo) is a standalone installation, the second (host: 192.168.233.128) is a local vmware.
I'm using a Git Bash as a client on my Windows machine.

Checking which key is currently represented by the agent:

```
$ ssh-add -L 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEApTDc2q+FKk5tmk7IOQhXXQ4OskQSiEuTv31TflRI1wrZbR2QQz/j6MCwwrP4bSF5ErU+n9DirfKRovpbf8TbVG5OXsHytuU5uKNgSqnXTcd8vpo7HhAplMblUJa3KbIfa4YXrIJcG+6FBzwJgWgoarDePtBUsICAXR7wjbR7Im0= open_ssh_key
```

My config has the same configuration for both hosts:

```
Host gitrepo
    HostName gitrepo
    IdentityFile C:\Users\userxx\.ssh\open_ssh_key
Host 192.168.233.128
    HostName 192.168.233.128
    IdentityFile C:\Users\userxx\.ssh\open_ssh_key
```

Below is a connection debug.

Successful connection (gitrepo):

```
$ ssh -vvv git@gitrepo
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for gitrepo
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "gitrepo" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitrepo [10.10.10.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitrepo:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys from gitrepo
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:hIW5BeJQWZNp4BLBB9/q/1Jh1Oi667DXH+RmlM/+Puw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys from gitrepo
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 126.185.117.237
debug1: Host 'gitrepo' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: open_ssh_key (0x600070c20), agent
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:D5Mo7JsVpHwjP6mnG76xIhTdpAmgc7ELD6oimH4Yokk open_ssh_key
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:D5Mo7JsVpHwjP6mnG76xIhTdpAmgc7ELD6oimH4Yokk
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:D5Mo7JsVpHwjP6mnG76xIhTdpAmgc7ELD6oimH4Yokk
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitrepo ([126.185.117.237]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Marek Białobrzewski!
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to gitrepo closed.
Transferred: sent 2552, received 2988 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10133.2, received 11864.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Unsuccessful connection (192.168.233.128)

```
$ ssh -vvv git@192.168.233.128
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for 192.168.233.128
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "192.168.233.128" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.233.128 [192.168.233.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.233.128:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.233.128
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:LSAj6IYpOTndWM9A2UNcD5Bgg46RF1wgh1qxyHRcYFU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.233.128
debug1: Host '192.168.233.128' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/userxx/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: open_ssh_key (0x60006e540), agent
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:D5Mo7JsVpHwjP6mnG76xIhTdpAmgc7ELD6oimH4Yokk open_ssh_key
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\userxx\\.ssh\\open_ssh_key
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:D5Mo7JsVpHwjP6mnG76xIhTdpAmgc7ELD6oimH4Yokk
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@192.168.233.128's password:
```

I'm not sure if the problem lies in a server's configuration. authenticated_keys holds the right key.
Compering the debugs:

```
receive apcket: type 7
```

and

```
receive packet: type 51
```

differs from each other... But I'm not sure what it indicates.

Any help, what to check, where the problem is would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the port 22 mapped? (https://communities.vmware.com/thread/471260)

Comment: @VonC Thats it! On the virtual machine ssh port was set not to default 22. Thank you.

Comment: Great! i have added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in [this thread](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/471260), you need to make sure the port 22 is mapped to your machine, in order to be able to access it.

Or you need to use the non-default port already mapped.